# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my Caesar algorithm?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

The output is wonky when I use numbers 4-22, and I can't figure out why. Help would be greatly appreciated, and I would also like to know why this does not work.

```
#include<cs50.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int shifts;
    int enc;
    printf("What is your message ");
    string message = get_string();
    printf("By how many letters do you want to shift?");
    scanf("%d",&shifts);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(message);i++)
    {
           enc=((message[i] - 89)+shifts)%26;
           printf("%c",enc + 89);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The number `89` seems wrong. Also, you should handle lower case and upper case separately.

Comment: Use character constants, not magic numbers like `89`

Comment: Also, there is memory leak in your code.

Comment: also, this isn't c

Comment: @KeithNicholas It is actually C. He is using that abomination called cs50.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya you got a link for that?

Comment: @KeithNicholas [This](https://reference.cs50.net/) is the reference page for CS50. Although looking into it would be a waste of time, it has lots of anti-patterns.

Comment: What is "wonky", some colloquial phrase for "strange in a way which I cannot describe, not even by giving sample input, resulting output and desired output" ? Please read [mcve], it does not only involve posting compileable code (which you did fine).

Comment: Bryan, CS50 has its own stack exchange site that will net you answers more specific to the C used on the CS50 course: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Inside the for loop you should check whether the character is uppercase, lowercase or neither. The number 89 is also wrong, that is 'Y', what you probably want is 65 or 97, 'a' and 'A' respectively. The for loop should be changed to be something like:

```
#include <ctype.h> // For isupper()/islower()
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(message); i++)
{
    if(isupper(message[i])) { // Check if current char is uppercase
        enc=((message[i] - 'A')+shifts)%26; // Apply cipher
        printf("%c",enc + 'A'); 
    } else if(islower(message[i])) { // Check if current char is lowercase
        enc=((message[i] - 'a')+shifts)%26; // Apply cipher
        printf("%c",enc + 'a');
    } else { // Print char without change
        printf("%c", message[i]);
    }
}
```

Note the use of 'A' and 'a' instead of 65 and 97, these will translate to the corresponding integer literals at compile time. There are other ways to write this, this probably isn't even the most clean way to do it (multiple printf()s for example), but it should illustrate how this works and should be done.